# how to click or select on very first element(value) of input dropdown box in python using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, splinter

I am a beginner in python web scraping and trying to automate the site. In the website which I want to scrape there is a searching filter, where I am applying filters on input box dropdown tag.
in the drop-down box, I  write the country name and all country come accordingly but I am unable to select or click the very first country that comes as a value in the dropdown box. I applied some code also but my script fails and terminated.
Below is the image for better understanding.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q8Fj.png)

I also applied some code, please check below

```
p_location='united states'

browser.find_by_xpath("//label[contains(.,'Geography')]").first.click()
        actions_wait_time = randint(15, 30)
        time.sleep(actions_wait_time)
        loc_input = browser.find_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Add locations']")
        loc_input.type(p_location)
        actions_wait_time = randint(15, 30)
        time.sleep(actions_wait_time)
        loc_input.type(Keys.TAB)
        time.sleep(3)
        loc_input.type(Keys.RETURN)
```

I want to select the first value from the dropdown list. Please help

Comment: Can  you supply the url? Or as a minimum, the html via [edit] using snippet tool provided. Please also include the current stack trace for the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to come up with the exact code without seeing the [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of the page, however one thing is obvious: you should not be using [time.sleep](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/) function as it is a some form of a performance anti-pattern.

You should go for [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead like:

```
loc_input = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Add locations']")))
first_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//xpath/for/the/first/element/in/the/dropdown")))
first_element.click()
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

Comment: sorry to say but XPATH id is changed randomly